# Using Pipeline with GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, pipeline, grid-search

Suppose I have this `Pipeline` object:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('my_transform', my_transform()),
    ('estimator', SVC())
])
```

To pass the hyperparameters to my Support Vector Classifier (SVC) I could do something like this:

```
pipe_parameters = {
    'estimator__gamma': (0.1, 1),
    'estimator__kernel': (rbf)
}
```

Then, I could use `GridSearchCV`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, pipe_parameters)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

We know that a *linear* kernel does not use gamma as a hyperparameter. **So, how could I include the *linear* kernel in this GridSearch?**

For example, In a simple `GridSearch` (without Pipeline) I could do:

```
param_grid = [
    {'C': [ 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 
     'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1],
     'kernel': ['rbf']},
    {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
     'kernel': ['linear']},
    {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
     'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1],
     'degree': [2, 3],
     'kernel': ['poly']}
]
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid)
```

Therefore, I need a working version of this sort of code:

```
pipe_parameters = {
    'bag_of_words__max_features': (None, 1500),
    'estimator__kernel': (rbf),
    'estimator__gamma': (0.1, 1),
    'estimator__kernel': (linear),
    'estimator__C': (0.1, 1),
}
```

Meaning that I want to use as hyperparameters the following combinations:

```
kernel = rbf, gamma = 0.1
kernel = rbf, gamma = 1
kernel = linear, C = 0.1
kernel = linear, C = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Similar to how you created multiple dictionaries for `SVC` model, create a list of dictionaries for the pipeline.

Try this example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.pipeline import pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC

categories = [
    'alt.atheism',
    'talk.religion.misc',
    'comp.graphics',
    'sci.space',
]
remove = ('headers', 'footers', 'quotes')

data_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories,
                                shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                                remove=remove)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('bag_of_words', CountVectorizer()),
    ('estimator', SVC())])
pipe_parameters = [
    {'bag_of_words__max_features': (None, 1500),
     'estimator__C': [ 0.1, ], 
     'estimator__gamma': [0.0001, 1],
     'estimator__kernel': ['rbf']},
    {'bag_of_words__max_features': (None, 1500),
     'estimator__C': [0.1, 1],
     'estimator__kernel': ['linear']}
]
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, pipe_parameters, cv=2)
grid.fit(data_train.data, data_train.target)

grid.best_params_
# {'bag_of_words__max_features': None,
#  'estimator__C': 0.1,
#  'estimator__kernel': 'linear'}
```